# tomcat 7 maxThreads selection criteria

Tags: tomcat, tomcat6, tomcat7

I am using tomcat 7 and wish to tune maxThreads attribute in server.xml.

Is there any selection criteria for this attribute ? I do have 8 GB RAM in my machine and allocates 4 GB RAM to tomcat JVM using -Xms and -Xmx JAVA_OPTS.

Let me know if you need more information.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum number of Threads you should use depends on your usecases, the expected response time of your requests,  the number of simultaneous your server should be able to handle, your cpu (for example the number of cores), your operating system,  ... 
The default of max 200 Threads is usually ok.
If you think you need to modify this value you should run some perfomance / stress tests and monitor the different response times of different configurations.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I set maxThreads 1000 and sent 2000 requests in 30 seconds from 2 different JVMs. But did not see any error like 'All tomcat threads are busy...' in catalina.out. Below is my machine information - CPU - Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           E5540  @ 2.53GHz, 4 cores, Ram - 8GB, allocates 4GB to tomcat JVM heap, OS is RHEL 5..... how many threads tomcat server on the start up launches ? I think , whenever needed it can create threads upto maxThreads value. Correct me if I am wrong.. Do you see any issue if I set maxThreads to such a high value say 1000 ?

Comment: 2000 request per 30 seconds are 66 requests per second. Even if the response time is 5 seconds you'll only need 330 Threads to handle all requests within 5 seconds. Your CPU can handle only 4(8 with hyper threading) requests really simultaneous. Any additional thread causes context switches which are expensive and Tomcat is not the only process on the machine. MinSpareThreads is the number of threads initial created default is 4. As told the actual max number of threads depends on your use-case and what your thread actually does. Is the thread waiting or consuming cpu time.